# Linked / Related questions with scores that have more than 2 digits display incorrectly STILL

Tags: bug, status-completed

[This related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229751/related-questions-with-over-99-score-display-incorrectly) on MSE shows as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) but for UX.SE, it's still a problem.

If you look at <strike>[this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/60958/users-will-adapt-to-your-ui)</strike> [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/ok-cancel-on-left-right), you'll notice that in the Linked / Related questions sections that scores are displayed incorrectly for those that are greater than 2 digits.

[image]

[image]

This has been captured on **Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153 m**.

Comment: Pretty sure that's a bug, never seen it before

Comment: Clicking through to the question shows that it's not downvotes. The vote count is over two digits and is wrapping. There's a [bug post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229751/212780) for the "related" questions on meta.so, but it's unfortunately marked status completed. There is [a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229428/212780) specifically for "linked", but it's closed as duplicate of the other. Either way, it happens for both linked and related here on UX :(

Comment: @Geobits - You're right. I'll update the question since it's still not fixed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had some issues reproducing this, but managed to repro it in Chrome as well as *some* versions of FireFox. A fix has been pushed and will be live in the next production build. Thanks for bringing this up!

Comment: I've updated my question with a different question that has issues in Linked and Related question sections and lists what browser version I saw them in.